# C# How can I Cast/Convert a IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, object>> to another type?

Tags: c#, casting, ienumerable, igrouping

So, I am trying to cast the following variable:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, object>> GroupedValues;
```

To this:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, int>> GroupedValues;
```

I have tried using Cast and also

```
Convert.ChangeType(GroupedValues, typeof(int));
```

but if It doesn't seem like a valid conversion if I compare it with a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, int>>` variable;

Comment: Does that `IGrouping<object,object>` really contains `int`s? If so, why is that typed as object in first place? Where do you get that instance from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast it because it's not contravariant- you could reproject it (assuming that all keys and values are castable to `int`):

```
var q = GroupedValues.SelectMany(g => g.Select (gv => new {Key = (int)g.Key, Item = (int)gv}))
                     .GroupBy (g => g.Key, g => g.Item);
```

Or change the initial query to case the key and items.

Comment: Thank you, it works as intended! I will however stick to Akhgary's solution as I consider it to be more elegant

Comment: @Innat3 I agree - That approach is cleaner and more clever.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

```
var result = GroupedValues.GroupBy(x => (int)x.Key, x => x.Cast<int>());
```

This will throw exception if any object is not `int`. so you can filter to get only integer items like this.

```
var result = GroupedValues.Where(x => x.Key is int && x.All(i => i is int)).GroupBy(x => (int)x.Key, x => x.Cast<int>());
```

Comment: Thank you it fixed my problem!